# Lime 5.2.1 / Android 4.3 : dlopen fails on stpcpy

Tags: android, android-ndk, haxe, openfl, hxcpp

I'm trying to build an empty HaxePunk project for Android to test the build chain, and while I'm never getting any error, all my attemps have crashed at run time with the same error message :

```
Error: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "stpcpy" referenced by libzlib.so...
```

I am running the executable on a pretty old phone with Android 4.3 on it ; a Sony Xperia M.

I have been doing a bit of research, and so far I mostly see the same things being repeated : update your NDK (I've been using the latest one from the android dev website and not the one `lime setup android` downloads), build for previous API versions (which I am also doing with `<config:android target-sdk-version="18" />` in my project.xml file). So I don't know what I'm doing wrong, if anything.

Another thing I found is that I'm using the git version of HXCPP, and when I built the Android libs with `neko build.n android` in the `project` subdir, it was using `-DHXCPP_ANDROID_PLATFORM=26` whereas the Lime build of my project is using `-DHXCPP_ANDROID_PLATFORM=9`, so that can't be good. However, I don't really know much about Android at all, but I have read that the SDK version and Android platform are two different things, or so I've read.

Any help with this will be much appreciated.

EDIT : Okay so something weird happened : up until now I was trying to install the APK manually by copying it to my phone's files and launching it from there, which kept crashing. I tried `lime test android` once without changing anything at all and it worked fine, and from then I could manually install the APK like I used to, and the error never happened again. I can't replicate it, but it's still an open case.

Comment: Yes, you should force **DHXCPP_ANDROID_PLATFORM** to be **android-18**. As https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/hxcpp/blob/master/tools/hxcpp/Setup.hx#L414 suggests, you can set **PLATFORM** in your *defines*.

Comment: Okay so something weird happened : up until now I was trying to install the APK manually by copying it to my phone's files and launching it from there, which kept crashing. I tried `lime test android` once without changing anything at all and it worked fine, and from then I could manually install the APK like I used to, and the error never happened again. I can't replicate it, but it's still an open case.